# Difference between OnOK() and CDialog::OnOK()

Tags: c++, mfc

What is the difference between OnOK() and CDialog::OnOK()? what should I use in this situation?

```
void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
    {

        //...some code here

        CDialog::OnOK();//?

        //OnOK();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There will be difference, if you have overridden `OnOK()` method.

The method is virtual, so if you call:

```
OnOK();  // equivalent of this->OnOK();
```

That will call the implementation according to virtual function table. I.e. implementation in your class or subclasses.

If you call:

```
CDialog::OnOK();
```

It is non-virtual function call of whatever is implementation in `CDialog` (or its supers).

Comment: OnOK();  was generated by VS wizard, but method  OnOK() is not generated overridden in CMyDlg:public CDialog class.  Maybe CDialog::OnOK();  "safer" to use?

Comment: @mrgloom More dangerous I would say, because if you have defined OnOK it will not be called.

Comment: @mrgloom It depends purely on what you want to achieve. For example, if you override `OnOK` method yourself, you most likely want to use `CDialog::OnOK()`. If you want to simulate "OK" user click, then you use a virtual call.